# PhpStorm - A way to insert variable-names in comments in live templates

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I'm trying to make this live template:

```
if( $COND$ ):
    $END$ 
endif; // if( $COND$ )
```

so that I can automatically add the same condition on the `endif` (in a comment), as I'm typing the actual if-condition.

However, PhpStorm thinks that `$COND$` is a comment, so it doesn't work.

---

The closest I can come is with this:

```
if( $COND$ ):
    $END$ 
endif; $COMMENT$ if ( $COND$ )
```

... so I can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then set the two comment-slashes manually, and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to enter the if-statement. Can it be optimized?

Comment: What **exactly** does not work? Some screencast/video is more than welcome (the best way to illustrate such dynamic stuff). Your initial Live Template works just fine for me in `.php` file in latest PhpStorm 2019.1.1

Comment: Hmm... This is wierd. It was printing out the last `$COND$`, instead of writing what I typed in the if-condition. But then I restarted PhpStorm, - and then it started working. Or maybe I had missed something, that I corrected, before I closed PhpStorm. Nevertheless. It's working now. Thanks for your assistance.